# Closet walls load bearing?

Tags: closet

In my room in my house there is an outset closet I believe and I want to know if the walls are structural because I cannot determine if they are myself I'll take a picture and post it and let me know if you can help me figure this out.[image]

Comment: Short walls are usually not load bearing, unless something heavy is above them.  A series of short walls with doorways/openings in a straight line might be load bearing and need more checking.  Is there a beam/wall under the floor supporting the short wall?

Comment: It might be outset because the behind/back wall of the closet is load bearing.  Adding doors to it would need a beam/bigger header over the doors.